# C# Dictionary with Private Add Method or Adjustment Ability

Tags: c#, dictionary, properties, private

I'm attempting to create a dictionary within a class that has a private Add method/ability to adjust the values. Basically I want to be able to access it from outside of the class and see the values within it, but I don't want anyone to be able to change the values associated with a key without working through the Methods in the Class.

I first attempted to create a Property that was a Dictionary (so I could easily attempt to do what I want with a getter and private setter) but then found out that this isn't exactly possible.

I understand that there is likely a way to do this with custom Methods or maybe a custom separate class, but I wanted to check here first to see if there were any way to do this already available in C#.

Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>` - it is a [interface all Dictionary classes implement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2).

But if that is the type of the Propery you expose, there **is** no `Add()` function to call. It has List and Collection "brothers", with the same deal.

Note that someone could technically still cast it back to `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, granting them full R/W access. This should not really mater in all but security applications. If it maters, just only hand out Clones of your internal Dictionary.

Code could look like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> SecuredCollection = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string> ThatDictionaryUsersCanOnlyRead
{
    get 
    {
        return SecuredCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, if you use your code above, do you really need to use an IReadOnlyDictionary? Couldn't you just use a dictionary at that point?

Comment: As he explains in the answer, `IReadOnlyDictionary` doesn't have an `Add` function to call (per your requirement of the caller not being able to add values). If you simply pass a Dictionary back, it will have the `Add()` implementation you're looking to avoid. By creating it as such here within your class, and exposing it only as an `IReadOnlyDictionary`, callers will only have the methods available to them as `IReadOnlyDictionary` provides.

Comment: Ahh, I gotcha. That is pretty secure. Makes sense. Actually acts as a Property with a private setter. I can change it from within the class with the SecruredCollection but can't screw with it from outside the class. Thanks, big help.

Also, just to be clear, he forgot to add the variable name for the IReadOnlyDictionary, correct? I'd like to think, I'm not missing something there, but hey, ya never know.

Comment: @whathm I did indeed forget the property name. That is what happens when you write purely on the website. I fixed it now.

Comment: @Christopher Exactly what I figured, I don't blame you. Makes perfect sense now, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe another solution is to simply return a new `Dictionary`, but with the desired `Dictionary` as a parameter for the new `Dictionary's` constructor. Similar to @Christopher's answer but with no `IReadOnlyDictionary`.

This way, even if someone tries to adjust it, it will fail. However, I guess that means it should come with the disclaimer that it would be very misleading for someone that doesn't know it is providing a clone. With this being said, I'd conclude that this is an alternative, but that @Christopher's solution being the better one.

```
private Dictionary<int, string> legitDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public Dictionary<int, string> ClonedDictionary
{
    get 
    {
        return new Dictionary<int, string>(legitDictionary);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to do it in a way that would involve only properties. Natural way to accomplish what you want would be to use methods:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> users = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public void Set(string key, string value)
    {
        if (users.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            users[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            users.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> ListUsers() 
    {
        return users;
    }
}
```

Note: Set method is public. You can use any access specifier like private.

Comment: The other answer shows how to do what requested with properties... And code in this answer *does not* show how to prevent `.ListUser().Add("foo", "bar")` from being used.